How do I send data to a specific field on a web page?
I am working with this web page created using cherrypy by someone else.  I want to display data values generated in the server.py script in the four lat/lon input boxes below the map. The 'left' input field is shown highlighted in the attached screenshot.

The four input fields are currently populated when the user draws a rectangle on the map, and the values are the min/max lat/lons corresponding to the rectangle.  If instead the user uploads a waypoint file, the program will generate these values from the file instead of the map. Unfortunately, the original creator of this app did not display the file-generated bounds in the min/max lat/lon fields, and I wish to correct this deficiency.
Here is the server.py code that generates the data to be displayed:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
import shutil
import cherrypy
import shelve
import time
import traceback
import fcntl
from genshi.filters import HTMLFormFiller
from xcsoar.mapgen.server.job import Job, JobDescription
from xcsoar.mapgen.server import view
from xcsoar.mapgen.georect import GeoRect
from xcsoar.mapgen.waypoints.parser import parse_waypoint_file

#cherrypy.config.update({'log.screen': True})
cherrypy.config.update({
         'log.screen': True,  # Log to stdout
         'log.error_file': 'error.log',  # Log errors to a file
         'log.access_file': 'access.log'  # Log access to a file
     })



class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, dir_jobs):
        self.__dir_jobs = os.path.abspath(dir_jobs)

    def too_many_requests(self):
        db = None
        lock = None
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(self.__dir_jobs):
                os.makedirs(self.__dir_jobs)
            lock = open(os.path.join(self.__dir_jobs, "requests.db.lock"), "a")
            fcntl.flock(lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
            db = shelve.open(os.path.join(self.__dir_jobs, "requests.db"))
            for ip in list(db.keys()):
                times = db[ip]
                for t in times:
                    if time.time() - t > 3600:
                        times.remove(t)
                if len(times) == 0:
                    del db[ip]
                else:
                    db[ip] = times
            ip = cherrypy.request.remote.ip
            if ip in db:
                if len(db[ip]) >= 3:
                    return True
                times = db[ip]
                times.append(int(time.time()))
                db[ip] = times
            else:
                db[ip] = [int(time.time())]
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            print(("Error: {}".format(e)))
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            return False
        finally:
            if lock != None:
                lock.close()
            if db != None:
                db.close()

    @cherrypy.expose
    @view.output("index.html")
    def index(self, **params):
        cherrypy.log('At the top of the index.html function, with params = %s' % params)
        if cherrypy.request.method != "POST":
            return view.render()

        name = params["name"].strip()
        cherrypy.log('params: name = %s, mail = %s, detail = %s' % (name, params["mail"], params["level_of_detail"]))

        if name == "":
            return view.render(error="No map name given!") | HTMLFormFiller(data=params)

        desc = JobDescription()
        desc.name = name
        desc.mail = params["mail"]
        desc.resolution = 3.0 if "highres" in params else 9.0
        desc.compressed = "compressed" in params
        desc.welt2000 = "welt2000" in params
        desc.level_of_detail = int(params["level_of_detail"])

        selection = params["selection"]
        waypoint_file = params["waypoint_file"]
        cherrypy.log('waypoint_file = %s, waypoint_filename = %s, selection = %s' % (waypoint_file.file, waypoint_file.filename, selection))
        cherrypy.log('waypoint_file = %s' % waypoint_file.file)

        #gfp added to determine 'waypoint_file' type
        # cherrypy.log('displaying lines from waypoint_file.file')
        # lines = waypoint_file.file.readlines()
        # for line in lines:
        #     cherrypy.log(line)


        if selection in ["waypoint", "waypoint_bounds"]:
            if not waypoint_file.file or not waypoint_file.filename:
                return view.render(error="No waypoint file uploaded.") | HTMLFormFiller(
                    data=params
                )

            try:
                filename = waypoint_file.filename.lower()
                cherrypy.log('in TRY block filename = %s' % filename)

                if not filename.endswith(".dat") and (
                    filename.endswith(".dat") or not filename.endswith(".cup")
                ):
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        "Waypoint file {} has an unsupported format.".format(
                            waypoint_file.filename
                        )
                    )
    
                # #241212 better way to write this boolean expression (filename already forced to lowercase)
                if not filename.endswith(".dat") and not filename.endswith(".cup"):
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        "Waypoint file {} has an unsupported format.".format(
                            waypoint_file.filename
                        )
                    )

                desc.bounds = parse_waypoint_file(
                    waypoint_file.filename, waypoint_file.file
                ).get_bounds()
                desc.waypoint_file = (
                    "waypoints.cup" if filename.endswith(".cup") else "waypoints.dat"
                )

                cherrypy.log(f'in server.py: {filename} bounds: left = {desc.bounds.left:.3f}, right: {desc.bounds.right:.3f}, top: {desc.bounds.top:.3f}, bot {desc.bounds.bottom:.3f}')
                return view.render(
                    error="Just after bounds display " + waypoint_file.filename
                ) | HTMLFormFiller(data=params)

            except:
                return view.render(
                    error="Unsupported waypoint file " + waypoint_file.filename
                ) | HTMLFormFiller(data=params)

        if selection in ["bounds", "waypoint_bounds"]:
            try:
                desc.bounds = GeoRect(
                    float(params["left"]),
                    float(params["right"]),
                    float(params["top"]),
                    float(params["bottom"]),
                )
            except:
                return view.render(error="Map bounds not set.") | HTMLFormFiller(
                    data=params
                )

        if desc.bounds.height() <= 0 or desc.bounds.width() <= 0:
            return view.render(error="Bounds are invalid.") | HTMLFormFiller(
                data=params
            )

        if desc.bounds.height() * desc.bounds.width() > 1000:
            return view.render(error="Selected area is too large.") | HTMLFormFiller(
                data=params
            )

        if self.too_many_requests():
            return view.render(
                error="You can generate only three maps per hour."
            ) | HTMLFormFiller(data=params)

        job = Job(self.__dir_jobs, desc)

        if desc.waypoint_file:
            waypoint_file.file.seek(0)
            cherrypy.log("In the 'desc.waypoint_file' routine")

            f = open(job.file_path(desc.waypoint_file), "w")
            try:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc=waypoint_file.file, fdst=f, length=1024 * 64)
            finally:
                f.close()

        desc.download_url = "/download?uuid=" + job.uuid
        job.enqueue()
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/status?uuid=" + job.uuid)

    @cherrypy.expose
    @view.output("status.html")
    def status(self, uuid):
        job = Job.find(self.__dir_jobs, uuid)
        if job is None:
            return view.render("error.html", error="Job not found!")
        status = job.status()
        if status == "Error":
            return view.render("error.html", error="Generation failed!")
        elif status == "Done":
            return view.render("done.html", name=job.description.name, uuid=uuid)
        return view.render(uuid=uuid, name=job.description.name, status=status)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def download(self, uuid):
        job = Job.find(self.__dir_jobs, uuid)
        if not job or job.status() != "Done":
            return self.status(uuid)
        return cherrypy.lib.static.serve_download(
            job.map_file(), job.description.name + ".xcm"
        )

In particular, the the following snipped actually generates the four data values to be displayed:
        desc.bounds = parse_waypoint_file(
            waypoint_file.filename, waypoint_file.file
        ).get_bounds()
        desc.waypoint_file = (
            "waypoints.cup" if filename.endswith(".cup") else "waypoints.dat"
        )

        cherrypy.log(f'in server.py: {filename} bounds: left = {desc.bounds.left:.3f}, right: {desc.bounds.right:.3f}, top: {desc.bounds.top:.3f}, bot {desc.bounds.bottom:.3f}')

I'm marginally competent in Python but embarrassingly incompetent on cherrypy and html, so please be kind.  I worked through a number of the cherrypy tutorials, but got lost before finding anything I recognized as relevant.

It looks like you need to pass this data to the .render() call and modify your HTML file to have value attributes in those <input> tags. They would need to render data passed into the template rendering engine through that render() call, accessing them by their context names. Do you have that on GitHub or somewhere? There's code in other modules that might give you some clue.

thanks for the hint.  I actually did se that 'render' call in another part of the code that sends error messages to the 'error' tag.  Still can't quite figure out how to modify the HTML code to do the same thing for the 'left/right/top/bottom tags', but I'm working on it!

Come by the matrix space and I may be able to help more interactivity sometime: https://matrix.to/#/#cherrypy-space:matrix.org

I just noticed there was a GitHub link on the web page. So I see that the genshi template engine is being used to render html. You have to use whatever syntax they expect. I saw some py- prefixed attributes and things like ${var_name} in the templates. So this is how you access the data.
